# In 上旬・中旬・下旬, why is 上 the start and 下 the end of the month?

Tags: words, kanji, etymology

I understand that 上旬 means the first 10 days of the month, and that 下旬 means the last (approximately) 10 days of the month. However, I would like to understand the underlying logic for the choice of 上 and 下 for the beginning and end (respectively) of the month.

After all, the later days of the month have higher numbers (21 22 23 etc), so isn't it counter-intuitive that they labeled with 下? There must be a different logical interpretation...

Comment: Does it really require a leap in logic? My calendars have the start of the month on the top.

Comment: If that's really all there is to it, then that would answer my question!

Comment: I don't know if there is a clear connection or not, but I explained this for myself by comparing it to vertical writing. You write from top to bottom, so 上 comes before 下 In Japanese.

Comment: Consider also the English phrase, "let's start from the top..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my comment above, I answered a bit tongue-in-cheek-ily that calendars have the start of the month at the top, but if you want a concrete reference for the meaning of it, one of the meanings of 上 is 順序が先のほう ([source](http://www.kanjipedia.jp/kanji/0003478400)). Another example of a word that uses this meaning is 上巻 "first volume" (of a manga series, etc.).